# Why does the shell for-loop get affected by another for-loop?

Tags: shell, for-loop

Why do two for loops affect each other?

In the code block below, the expected output is:

```
before: a
after: a
before: c
after: c
```

but the actual output is:

```
before: a
after: a
before: c
after: b # changed, why ?
```

my test code is like below:

```
function checkExists() {
  d=$1
  for v in "a" "b"  # it seems to be affected by this line, why?
  do
    if [[ $v == $d ]]; then
      return 1
    fi
  done

  return 0
}

function start() {
  for v in "a" "c"
  do
    echo "before: $v"
    checkExists "$v"
    echo "after: $v"
  done
}

start
```

Why do two for loops affect each other?

Comment: Put `local v` in both functions. And don't use the `function` keyword -- it's left over from 1980s-era ksh; ever since the 90s, `checkExists() {` has been standardized. (Moreover, `function foo() {` mixes the POSIX `foo() {` and the ksh `function foo {` in a way that's incompatible with **both** POSIX and legacy ksh).

Comment: You can avoid any assignment by: `checkExists()( case $1 in a|b) return 1;; *) return 0;; esac )`. Conventionally, return 0 means success.

Comment: FWIW, `function foo` does work in bash, ksh, and zsh, though I agree you shouldn't mix it with `()`. Also, even modern ksh still treats `function` functions differently from `()` functions; you only get local variables in the `function` kind.

Comment: Just a hint, complementing the remark given by Charles Duffy: If it is an option for you to switch from POSIX shell to zsh, you could put at the start of your script `setopt warn_create_global`, and the shell would detect this type of errors.  I do it as a habit and it has already caught some errors. AFIK, POSIX shell does not offer a similar feature

Comment: @user1934428, incidentally, I wrote a library with a similar feature for bash -- see the leak detection in https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/declarative.bash/blob/master/declarative.bash

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No? ksh2020:  ```ksh -c 'foo() { local i=1; }; foo; echo $i'``` generates ```ksh: local: local can only be used in a function``` and then prints 1. The `local` works fine if I declare `function foo` instead, however.

Comment: @MarkReed, interesting. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't declare `v` as `local`. Therefore both functions are using the same variable. After you call `checkExists`, `v` will always be set to "b".

Unlike in some languages, shell `for` loops don't create their own independent world; they use a regular variable. If it's a variable that already existed before the loop starts, whatever value it used to have will be clobbered by the loop. And after the loop completes, whether it was new or preexisting, the variable is still around with whatever value it received on the last iteration.

And if you don't declare the variable as local inside the function containing the `for` loop (with e.g. `local v`), it will be a global variable that is seen by the function's caller as well.

Note that local variables are not a feature of the POSIX shell specification, however. The `local` declaration works in bash, ksh, zsh, and even the relatively-strict dash, but if you need your script to work in strictly-POSIX sh, you just have to pick variable names that don't conflict.